# Is trap EXIT required to execute in case of SIGINT or SIGTERM received?

Tags: shell, error-handling, signals, shell-trap

I have a simple script

```
trap 'echo exit' EXIT
while true; do sleep 1; done
```

and it behaves differently in different shells:

```
$ bash tst.sh
^Cexit
$ dash tst.sh
^C
$ zsh tst.sh
^C
$ sh tst.sh
^Cexit
```

So I'm not sure about how it should operate and whether it is specified at all.

Comment: busybox does also not run the EXIT trap on interrupts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EXIT` trap isn't working the same way in every shell. A few examples:

- In dash and zsh it's only triggered by a regular exit from within the script.
- In zsh, if you trap a signal that would normally quit the execution, you need
  to restore the default behaviour by explicitly calling `exit`.

I'd suggest you to actually catch the signals and then exit, it should be portable
across most shells:

```
$ cat trap
trap 'echo exit; exit' INT TERM  # and other signals
while true; do sleep 1; done
$ bash trap
^Cexit
$ dash trap
^Cexit
$ zsh trap
^Cexit
$ ksh trap
^Cexit
$ mksh trap
^Cexit
$ busybox sh trap
^Cexit
```

Comment: Ad `EXIT` trap isn't working the same way in every shell see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240723/exit-trap-in-dash-vs-ksh-and-bash/240736#240736